# Select rows which match condition and the following row

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following trivial data.table (the real data isn't as predictable):

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(seq(-5, 5, by = 2),
                       seq(-8, 4, by = 4)))
```

If I want to select all the negative values, I can simply do `dt[a < 0]`.

```
    a
1: -5
2: -3
3: -1
4: -8
5: -4
```

However, what if I want to get all the negative values ***and*** the first non-negative value after each sequence of negatives? That is, what if I want the output to be:

```
    a
1: -5
2: -3
3: -1
4:  1
5: -8
6: -4
7:  0
```

I can't figure out how to group or use `rleid()` to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `shift` with `sign` to get next row after negative row.

```
library(data.table)
dt[a < 0 | shift(sign(a) == -1)]

#    a
#1: -5
#2: -3
#3: -1
#4:  1
#5: -8
#6: -4
#7:  0
```

A shorter approach suggested by OP

```
dt[a < 0 | shift(a < 0)]
```

Comment: Any reason to use `sign(a) == -1` with `shift` instead of just repeating `a < 0`?

Comment: @Wasabi yeahh..that would work too actually. `dt[a < 0 | shift(a < 0)]`

Comment: and also `dt[{x<-a<0;x | shift(x)}]`

Comment: Similar to chinsoon's, another way to avoid calculating a < 0 twice: `dt[do.call(pmin, shift(sign(a), 0:1, fill=0L)) == -1L]`